# find: meaning of the \? sign as a value of the name parameter

Tags: command-line, find, wildcards

What is the meaning of the ? sign in the following command?

```
find /foo/path -name \?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `?` is part of a mechanism called ["pathname expansion" in the shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html).

Colloquially, the shell mechanism is called "globing". The basic glob makes use just of three characters: `*` `?` and `[` that build "patterns".

An asterisk `*` means:

- Any character in any quantity (any string).

A question mark (`?`) means:

- Any character **one time**.

The square braces define a character list `[ ]`, and mean:

- Only the characters inside the list counted once. There may exist negated lists.

Those [characters are used in a similar way in the command find](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Base-Name-Patterns). In find, they are called "patterns".

That means that there are two entities using the same characters to perform the same task (globing). One has to be told to ignore those characters. The usual way to tell the shell to avoid interpretation of special characters is to "quote them". Either with 'single quotes', "double quotes" or with a backslash:

```
'?'
"?"
\?
```

That is why the "patterns" for `find` are quoted:

```
find /path/foo -name \?
```

What that line means is:

List all files and directories starting from the directory `/path/foo` that have a name of only one character wide.

## about /

Note that ? in find's pattern expansion may match a `/`.

[A `pattern` in find can match a `/` as specified by POSIX inside the operands section for the find command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html#tag_20_47_05):

> -path  pattern
>    The primary shall evaluate as true if the current pathname matches pattern using the pattern matching notation described in Pattern Matching Notation. The additional rules in Patterns Used for Filename Expansion do not apply as this is a matching operation, not an expansion.

Again: additional rules ... for Filename Expansion (as in a shell) do not apply as this is a matching operation, not an expansion.

To show that this is true:

```
$ mkdir test; cd test
$ mkdir -p a/b/c/d
$ find a -path 'a?b'
a/b
$ find . -path './a?b?c?d'
./a/b/c/d
```

Of course, the `-name` option of find will match the **basename** of a file. That, by definition, could not have a `/` as is not possible to match a `/` in a basename.

Comment: It's not pathname expansion here, it's just pattern matching by find. pathname expansion (or globbing) refers to the shell behaviour of expanding a pattern into a list of matching files.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Both the shell "pathname expansion" and the "pattern matching" of find are [based on the same notation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html#tag_20_47_05): `matches pattern using the pattern matching notation described in` [Pattern Matching Notation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13). Therefore: the description of one notation also apply (with some differences) to the other. One difference is that find's patterns could match an slash `/`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Could you try `find /tmp -path '?tmp*'` and tell if it matches several files **and** slashes or not?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas And since I am already asking you, could you please try and say what is the result of this command?: `mkdir -p one/two/three; find one -path 'one?two?three'`

Comment: see [follow-up in /dev/chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29918506#29918506)

Answer (score 3):

`?` is a special character in [pattern matching](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13), which match any single character.

So the command means find all files and directories in `/foo/path` and its subdirectories, whose names are exactly one character long.

The `\?` is used to prevent your shell from performing [filename generation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_06). You can use other [quoting mechanisms](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02):

```
find /foo/path -name '?'
```

or:

```
find /foo/path -name "?"
```

---

Note that `?` in [filename expansion patterns](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13_03) never matches `/`, and also that the pattern given to `-name`, because of the slash,which will be ignored when computing the [basename()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/basename.html) of the file (A [basename](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_40) is the final, or only, filename in a pathname. And a [filename](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_170), in pathname context, can be followed by trailing slashes):

```
$ mkdir a b
$ find a/ b/ -name a -o -name b\?
a/
```

outputs `a/` only.

The only exception is `/` and `//` on implementations where `//` doesn't refer to `/`:

```
$ find / ! -path / -prune -o -name \? -print
/
```

([The POSIX definition is a bit unclear about the basename of `/`, `//` and `///+`](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29886699#29886699))

or in busybox find:

```
$ busybox find a/ b/ -name a -o -name b\?
b/
```

---

If you try using `/` in the pattern given to `-name`, then the behavior varies depending on the implementation.

BSD find and heirloom find treat the expression as false, output nothing:

```
$ find /tmp -name /tmp
$ echo "$?"
0
```

GNU find gives you the warning message:

```
$ find /tmp -name /tmp
find: warning: Unix filenames usually don't contain slashes (though pathnames do).
That means that '-name ‘/tmp’' will probably evaluate to false
all the time on this system. You might find the '-wholename' test more useful,
or perhaps '-samefile'. Alternatively, if you are using GNU grep,
you could use 'find ... -print0 | grep -FzZ ‘/tmp’'.
```

And its return code is 0.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40317/discussion-on-answer-by-cuonglm-find-meaning-of-the-sign-as-a-value-of-the-n).

Comment: @cuonglm The filename expansion patterns are not applicable to find patterns.